# How to fetch time from ObjectId in mongodb database..?

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query

I actually want to fetch time and store it to variable...which i have highlighted..how can i do..!?

{"_id" : { "$oid" : "54ae118fb283f33e88cc3281"}, "nodes" : [ {- - - - - } ] }

_id(ObjectId) : 54ae118fb283f33e88cc3281
      **Time** : 1420693903000 = **Thu Jan 08 10:41:43 IST 2015**
      Machine : 2994991934
      Inc : 2295083649

Comment: You are better off storing a discreet property for the timestamp in your document if you want to use that in any meaningful query form. You can extract a timestamp value from the `ObjectId`, but you can only do it in client code as the server has no native methods to do this. The only way to return a timestamp from an `ObjectId` from the server is with JavaScript and mapReduce. The value in the `ObjectId` is only accurate to the second, and therefore not really optimal.

Comment: `code` DBCollection node_info = db.getCollection("node_info");
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
        ObjectId id = (ObjectId)query.get( "_id" );
        System.out.println(id);
Can't i get like this ??

Comment: Yes that is "client" code. But you cannot do that on the server really. So you cannot use the `ObjectId` to select dates within a range. That alone is a good reason to have a separate timestamp field.

Comment: okk...then is there any other way to get time ?
Actually i want time of last inserted id..

Answer (score 1):

finally got the solution :

```
public String getLastUpdatedTime(){

    String timevalue = null;

    DBCollection node_info = db.getCollection("node_info");
    ObjectId id = (ObjectId)node_info.findOne().get( "_id" );
    timevalue = String.valueOf(id.getTime());
    Date dt = new Date(Long.parseLong(timevalue));
    //System.out.println(dt);
    timevalue = String.valueOf(dt);
    return timevalue;
}
```

Comment: Just remember that the _id doesn't change when the document is updated so the method name getLastUpdatedTime() is a bit misleading

Comment: ya that's true but when document got updated at the same time TIME is also updated for that document & _id remains same..so i can get final document updated time..

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId to joda DateTime:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId   
   
val objectid = new ObjectId("616ebb7f3271a555ccfcf0f1")
new org.joda.time.DateTime(objectid.getDate)
// val res0: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2021-10-19T14:35:11.000+02:00
```